# Сортировка очереди

Tags: c

Элемент очереди:

```
typedef struct List{
    int key;
    char name[30];
    struct List * next;
}tList;
```

Функция для обмена элементов

```
void elements_swap(tList * elem1,tList * elem2){
    tList *n_bufer,*prev1,*prev2,*cp = begin_line;

    while(cp!= NULL){
        if(cp->next == elem1){
            prev1 = cp;
        }
        if(cp->next == elem2){
            prev2 = cp;
        }
        cp = cp->next;
    }

    prev1->next = elem2;
    prev2->next = elem1;
    n_bufer = (tList*)elem1->next;
    elem1->next = elem2->next;
    elem2->next = n_bufer;
}
```

Проблема в том, что происходит сравнения и присвоение указателей разных типов, т.е. на этом моменте происходит краш программы `prev2->next = elem1;`

Есть ли решение кроме как убрать `typedef` ?

Comment: Что-то у меня подозрение, что у вас ошибка в том, что `prev2`, скажем, нулевое. Потому что `typedef` тут в полной мере ни при чем. Да, и допишите, как у вас определена `begin_line` (почему, например, вы не передаете это значение в виде аргумента).

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее, что у вас будет, если `begin_line` указывает на `elem1` или `elem2`?

Comment: все, спасибо большое разобрался.